# SOQL: Inner query on lookup field

Tags: soql, inner

I have a table which has self lookup for the field name parent_id. I want to get the product code for the corresponding parent_id.

please let me know whats wrong with this query:

```
SELECT p.id,p.Name,p.productcode,

(select productcode from Products__r where Parent__id=p.id limit 1)

FROM product p
```

it works fine if I hardcode the where clause id, for exmaple

```
SELECT p.id,p.Name,p.productcode,

(select productcode from Products__r where Parent_id='1' limit 1)

FROM product p
```

Salesforce Table:

[image]

SQL for the above results will be like this :

Select id, Name, product_code, (select product_code from product b where b.parent_id=a. id) as products__r from product a

Can someone please convert the above SQL to SOQL?

Comment: Do you want to get all child records of Product p?

Comment: please check the required results above

Comment: Is sfdcfox's answer doesn't work for you? Your question is still not much clear.

Comment: No sfdcfox's answer is not working for me.  I have both child and parent records in a table. there is a self lookup field called parent_id which stores the parent _id for a child record. if its a parent record then the parent_id is 0, for a child record it stores the id of the parent . Now in my query I want to know the product code of the parent code (see the results above) . In SQL it can be done like this - Select a.id, a.Name, a.product_code, (select product_code from product b where b.parent_id=a. id) as products__r from producct a

Comment: Check the more details provided in question. Table Values and SQL

Comment: SFDC query will work you just need to iterate them.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for a filter; the sub-query does this for you automatically. The following query should work:

```
SELECT Name, productcode,
(select productcode from Products__r limit 1)
FROM product2
```

Note that you can't currently compare fields to each other in SOQL, there's a few Ideas out there for that, but it will likely take a while to see this become available.

Comment: It did not solve my problem . you query returns Child 'd product code against the parent record; but I want the parent's code for a child record. Please see the required results above

Comment: `there's a few Ideas out there for that` would you mind linking those?

Comment: @zaitsman https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrHAAA0 https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kpH0AAI https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kmzpAAA ...